# How to get to work handlers in GAE for email in url

Tags: google-app-engine

If i have a url like this www.myurl.com/test@test.com I would like to get the index.html
if I dont have the mail I want the same.

```
application: myapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /AJAX
  script: main.py




- url: /
  static_files: static_files/index.html
  upload: static_files


- url: /
  static_dir: static_files

- url: /*
  static_files: static_files/index.html
  upload: static_files
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the last section in the handler group to

```
- url: /.*
  static_files: static_files/index.html
  upload: static_files
```

it should match any URL.